# What's the difference between depends and build-depends in debian/control file of dpkg?

Tags: dpkg

Can anyone please explain what exactly is the difference between depends and build-depends?

Somewhere, I read in build-depends, we add packages required for building our package. As per my understanding, anything needed for building my executable/library should be added here. It may include tools like cmake as well as other dependencies.

And in depends, we put dependencies needed for installation. I don't understand this.

Can anyone please explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"build-depends" is used to list down the packages which are required to build / create the debian package.

"Depends" lists out the packages which are used for the functioning of the package i.e. when **dpkg -i <package_name>** is run, it will first install the packages listed under "Depends" and then install the final package as the final package is exporting / using the functionality of the packages defined in "Depends".